# crystal report to pdf without report viewer

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports

I would like to know how to export crystal report to `pdf` format file without pointing to crystal report viewer in code. Below is my working code with report viewer but I would want to do so without it.

```
   private void getReportDocument()
    {
        using (connection = new MySqlConnection(strPigen_Deposit_Conn))
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
                try
                {
                    ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
                    cryRpt.Load("cryPaymentAdvise.rpt");
                    ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
                    ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
                    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                    paramField.Name = "pDataID";
                    paramDiscreteValue.Value = strDataID;
                    paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                    paramFields.Add(paramField);
                    crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
                    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
                    cryRpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "PaymentAdvise.pdf");


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    return;
                }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way
you can't.

If you want manage crystaleport you need crystalReportViewer.

If you want create a PDF without installing CrystalReports runtime, there are many solutions, but this is not your question.